# customising the data before exporting to excel using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net page with a gridview. I need to export the gridview to excel but need to modify the colmnns data before exporting. I am using below code to export:

```
 Response.Clear();

 Response.Buffer = true;         

   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileName.xls");
   Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

   StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
   gvLogs.RenderControl(hw);
   gvLogs.AllowPaging = false;
   gvLogs.DataBind(); // bind data 
   Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
   //need to call Flush and End methods 
   Response.Flush();
   Response.End();
```

It works but it exports the grid to excel with same columns data as grid like this:

```
asif@cc.com my company1aa viewed profile abc@gmail.com my name  Company views profile   7/24/2013 11:18
asif@cc.com my company1aa viewed profile cv3@cc.com cv 3    Company views profile   7/24/2013 11:18
asif@cc.com my company1aa viewed profile cv2@cc.com cv 2    Company views profile   7/24/2013 11:17
asif@cc.com my company1aa viewed profile cv4@cc.com cv 4    Company views profile   7/24/2013 11:17
asif@cc.com my company1aa viewed profile CV1@cc.com cv 1    Company views profile   7/24/2013 11:16
```

I want to break first column to 4 columns such that ( in case of first row)

```
Employer email = asif@cc.com
company name = my company1aa
Registrant email = abc@gmail.com
Full name = my name

and then remaining 2 columns as it is

Action = Compnay view Profile
Date = 7/24/2013 11:18
```

Please suggest how can I do this. I am using object data source for binding but I can get data table:

```
HRActionLog actionLog = new HRActionLog();
           DataTable dt = actionLog.GetList(Action,DateFrom,DateTo,CompanyId,RegistrantId,VacancyId,CurrentLanguage);
```

Do I need to create a new datatable with additional columns and populate it from dt ?

Please suggest

Comment: I would create a new datatable. IMHO this is the quickest and cleanest way.

Comment: @Koen How to break first column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you can't get the data from somewhere, the only option I see is to split the string into different parts using [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split.aspx)
I'm not fond of it, but I don't see any other solution.

Taking into account that the string will always be in the format as you've given you can use the following snippet:

```
    var lst = new List<string>
                  {
                      "asif1@cc.com my company1aa1 viewed profile abc@gmail.com my name",
                      "asif2@cc.com my company1aa2 viewed profile cv3@cc.com cv 3",
                      "asif3@cc.com my company1aa3 viewed profile cv2@cc.com cv 2",
                      "asif4@cc.com my company1aa4 viewed profile cv4@cc.com cv 4",
                      "asif5@cc.com my company1aa5 viewed profile CV1@cc.com cv 1"
                  };
    foreach (var str in lst)
    {
        var i = str.IndexOf("viewed", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        var part1 = str.Substring(0, i - 1); // -1 ommits the space before "viewed"
        var employerEmail = part1.Substring(0, part1.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        Console.WriteLine("EmployerEmail :" + employerEmail);
        var companyName = part1.Substring(part1.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1); // +1 ommits the space
        Console.WriteLine("CompanyName :" + companyName);

        var part2 = str.Substring(i + 16); // +16 to start right after "viewed profile "
        var registrantEmail = part2.Substring(0, part2.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        Console.WriteLine("RegistrantEmail :" + registrantEmail);
        var fullName = part2.Substring(part2.IndexOf(" ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 1); // +1 ommits the space
        Console.WriteLine("FullName :" + fullName);
    }
```

This code will only work when the strings are in format

```
<email> <companyname> viewed profile <email> <fullname>
```

If this changes, you'll have to adapt the snippet.
But as mentioned on top: if you can find this data somewhere in the database, it's a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

As @Koen said creating a new datatable is the best option.

As for breaking the first column into smaller strings / variables you would require a complex regexp and would still be prone to errors due to the fact that the string in your first column will, most probably, vary greatly.